# Measurement on a specific basis and proof of circuit output

Tags: quantum-gate, measurement, vqe, pauli-gates, optimization

I am trying to understand a proof from [Practical optimization for hybrid quantum-classical algorithms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.01450). In particular, I need clarifications on how do you perform the measurement on a different basis presented below and the last step of the proof.

First, let's start with some notation: $V(\theta)$ is an ansatz of the most general shape
\begin{equation}
V({\theta})=\prod_{l=1}^{L}V_l(\theta_l)W_l
\end{equation}
Where $V_l(\theta_l)=\exp(-i\theta_lU_l)$, $U_l$ is an Hermitian operator, $W_l$ is also an unitary (doesn't matter now). Moreveover, you can always decompose $U$ as a linear combination of Paulis $U_l=\sum_{\mu}^{l_U}u_\mu \sigma_{\mu}^{(U)}$. Similarly, for any Hermitian $H=\sum_{\nu}^{l_G}h_\nu \sigma_{\nu}^{(H)}$. Finally, when "splitting" the gate sequence $V$ we write in short $V_-=\prod_{l=1}^{k-1}V_l(\theta_l)W_l$ and $V_+=\prod_{l=k}^{L}V_l(\theta_l)W_l$

[image]

Given this circuit, I am trying to understand the output presented by the author. The proof goes as follows:

Applying $V_-$ and $H$ to the initial state yields: $V_-|{\textbf{0}}\rangle(|{0}\rangle+|{1}\rangle)(1/\sqrt{2})$. Then, a controlled $\sigma_{\mu}^{(U)}$ gate results in
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(V_-|{\textbf{0}}\rangle|{0}\rangle+\sigma_{\mu}^{(U)}V_-|{\textbf{0}}\rangle|{1}\rangle     \right)
\end{equation*}
then
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(V_-|{\textbf{0}\rangle}|{0}\rangle+\sigma_{\mu}^{(U)}V_-|{\textbf{0}}\rangle|{1}\rangle     \right) \xrightarrow{S, V_+} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(V|{\textbf{0}}\rangle|{0}\rangle+iV_+\sigma_{\mu}^{(U)}V_-|{\textbf{0}}\rangle|{1}\rangle     \right)
\end{equation*}
finally, an Hadamard on the ancilla and the circuit output is:
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
&|{\psi_{\mu}}\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(V|{\textbf{0}}\rangle|{+}\rangle+iV_+\sigma_{\mu}^{(U)}V_-|{\textbf{0}}\rangle|{-}\rangle\right)= \\
& = \frac{1}{2}[(V|{\textbf{0}}\rangle+iV_+\sigma_{\mu}^{(U)}V_-|{\textbf{0}}\rangle)|{0}\rangle        +(V|{\textbf{0}}\rangle-iV_+\sigma_{\mu}^{(U)}V_-|{\textbf{0}}\rangle)|{1}\rangle)]
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Now comes the difficult bit, which is measuring along a different basis on a set of qubits, and measuring on the canonical on the ancilla.
The author says: Recalling that $\langle i|\hat{\sigma}_{z}^{(a)}|j\rangle=\delta_{i j}(-1)^{j},$ one can easily verify that:

\begin{equation}
        \left\langle\psi_{\mu}\left|\hat{\sigma}_{\nu}^{(H)} \otimes \hat{\sigma}_{z}^{(a)}\right| \psi_{\mu}\right\rangle=-\Im\left[\left\langle 0\left|V^{\dagger} V_{+} \hat{\sigma}_{\mu}^{(U)} \hat{V}_{+}^{\dagger} \hat{\sigma}_{\nu}^{(H)}V\right| 0\right\rangle\right]
\end{equation}

- **How do you prove this very last step?**
- How do you *practically* implement this measurement operator above if you were to implement it on a QC? (You can also use an example, like assume $\sigma_v$ is $X$ on some qubits or whatever you prefer).

Don't hesitate to ask for clarifications if necessary, I am open to suggestions to improve this question.
When answering, please do so in a simple and understandable format, without skipping too many steps so that a beginner can also understand